# Code-Folding Code on RichTextBox using TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, code-folding

I'm currently developing an IDE and Im working on Code-Folding codes now .
I'm thinking to use a TreeView as for it has a collapse and expand property but i dunno/not sure how can I implement it on RichTextBox .

Even an Initial Code showing if interaction within RichTextBox and TreeView will be much appreciated .

```
like:

{

}

then RichTextBox will have a line indicating till where to collapse .
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem feasible to include a TreeView *inside* a RichTextBox. From my experience, building something atop the RTB is quite problematic and doesn't render the desired result without having quite a lot of quirks.

I suggest taking a look at the Fast-Colored-TextBox:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Or possibly building a similar control from scratch (if you too suffer from [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)) instead of attempting to extend the RTB.

Comment: i already saw the fastcolored @DeadDog ... problem was itdoesnt support some "RichTextBox" property which i really the most

Comment: Which properties are those?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need your own code editor you should really think about taking [Avalon Edit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor). It is able to rebuilt an Visual Studio Editor. So it has all you feature you need (and more).

I know it is a WPF component and not winforms. But it is quite easy to [host a WPF control within winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751761.aspx). So better take this route, cause trying to interweave a tree view with a rich text box will never match exactly what you like (just think about finding out the pixel size of a textline if you are using different fonts or how to determine line wrapping).

Comment: I also recommend a "real" source code editor, a Windows.Forms one would be ICSharpCode.TextEditor: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor

Comment: @Oliver ,

thanks sirs for the help but I have those now ... all i wanted was separate code for code-folding

Comment: same as @PacMani i already saw those but still thanks ... i needed separate code for code-folding sirs

Comment: @Elegiac: However, be careful before you put too much work into the RichTextBox. We fell into the abyss trying to implement special things with it, because the RTB often didn't work as expected ;-)

Comment: but it is Possible@PacMani ?